# How can I fix incorrect flat lines on my PowerBI line chart with a date hierarchy?

Tags: date, powerbi, hierarchy, linechart

I have a PowerBI report with a line chart that shows average costs over a time period. The time period is based on a date that is set to use a date hierarchy for the year and the month.

[image: X-axis]

When I open the report the line chart does not display correctly. The lines are incorrectly flat.

[image: Incorrect lines]

If I change the date from a date hierarchy to just the date and then back to the hierarchy, then it displays correctly.

[image: Correct lines]

This also happened when I published the report to the PBI service. What can be done to negate the need to do this?

I have tried resetting the field for the X-axis and restarting the application.

Comment: You'll want to click the double arrow icon to expand to next level by default. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-drill#drill-down-all-fields-at-once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking on the double arrow icon to expand the next level by default resolved my issue.